# stdio precision fprint

Tags: c, syntax, printf

This is a homework assignment. I have done all the coding besides this 1 piece. This is an example of what it should look like. except the employee name

```
Employee's   Pay      RegHours    Gross    Fed      SSI     Net
Name         Rate     OvtHours    Worked   State    Defr
==========   =====    ========   =======  ======   ======   ======
Smith, Sam   25.00       40.00   1000.00  127.50   65.88    647.70
                          5.00              8.93  150.00
```

Currently this is what it looks like.

> ```
>    Employee's   Pay      RegHours    Gross    Fed      SSI     Net
>    Name         Rate     OvtHours    Worked   State    Defr
>    ==========   =====    ========   =======  ======   ======   ======
>    Smith        25.00       40.00   1000.00  127.50   65.88    647.70
>    Sam                       5.00              8.93  150.00
>
>    Jordan       35.00       32.00   1120.00  149.25   77.11    758.19
>    Michael                   0.00             10.45  125.00
>
>    Totals:      60.00       72.00   2120.00  276.75  142.99   1405.89
>                              5.00             19.37  275.00
>    Averages:    30.00       36.00   1060.00  138.38   71.49    702.95
>                              2.50              9.69  137.50
> ```

It specifically says: "The employee's name must be printed as shown in the the report above with a comma and a space separating the first and last name."
  I am having trouble getting it to space properly.

My format is this:

```
#define HEADERLINE1 "       Employee's   Pay      RegHours    Gross    Fed      SSI     Net\n"
#define HEADERLINE2 "       Name         Rate     OvtHours    Worked   State    Defr\n"
#define HEADERLINE3 "       ==========   =====    ========   =======  ======   ======   ======\n"
#define REPLNEFORMT1 "       %-12.15s%6.2f%12.2f%10.2f%8.2f%8.2f%10.2f\n"//Main Header Line 1
#define REPLNEFORMT2 "       %-12s%18.2f%18.2f%8.2f\n\n"//Main Header Line 2
#define REPLNEFORMT3 "       %-11s%7.2f%12.2f%10.2f%8.2f%8.2f%10.2f\n"//Totals Line 1 
#define REPLNEFORMT4 "       %30.2f%18.2f%8.2f\n"//Totals Line 2    
#define REPLNEFORMT5 "       %-11s%7.2f%12.2f%10.2f%8.2f%8.2f%10.2f\n"//Averages Line 1 
#define REPLNEFORMT6 "       %30.2f%18.2f%8.2f\n"//Averages Line 2
```

This is how I print:

```
fprintf(stdout,REPLNEFORMT1,ln,p,h<=40?h:40,g,fed,ssi,n);  
fprintf(stdout,REPLNEFORMT2,fn,ovt,state,d);
fprintf(reportfile,REPLNEFORMT1,ln,p,h<=40?h:40,g,fed,ssi,n);  
fprintf(reportfile,REPLNEFORMT2,fn,ovt,state,d);
```

ln = last name, fn = first name, p = pay, h = hours, g = gross, n = net.

I can not use iostream, thus std precision is out of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char result[50];

strcpy(result, ln);
strcat(result, ", ");
strcat(result, fn);
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Use tabs to line up your columns, not spaces.

Comment: That will still cause misaligned columns if any data item is wider than one tabstop (which is not necessarily 8 columns).

Comment: Well, yes, but your column widths are limited by your column headings so your data items are already limited that way.  See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25366k66.aspx